# VSTO COM Add-In ProgID

Tags: excel, com, vsto, installshield, vba

I'm having an issue where the `ProgID` of the Add-in is **MyAddin** whereas I want it to be **MyAddin.Connect** because there's a lot of existing spreadsheets where the VBA references **MyAddin.Connect**.

I've changed every instance of MyAddin to MyAddin.Connect in the **csproj** file, **manifest**, and **vsto** file.  I've changed every instance in the registry.

> Even the registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\MyAddIn
>   to MyAddIn.Connect

Still when I check the `ProgID` through VBA, it says MyAddin (the friendly name in the COM Add-Ins Manager is MyAddin.Connect).

Where exactly is the `ProgID` loaded from within VBA in Excel? I should note it was working perfectly when I was debugging the AddIn through Visual Studio.  But when I install it through a InstallShield setup, it just refuses to work.

Answer (score 1):

When we debug the AddIn through the Visual Studio, the entry for AddIn is get added into registry and from there it load that addin.

While installing the AddIn from InstallShield we need to check whether we properly added registry entry for AddIn or not.

Also check the same registry entry under `HKCU` branch. Because addin gets loaded from HKCU branch as well of registry.